# Is a section of a book published in a journal considered a journal source?

Tags: citations

I have an assignment that requires one academic journal source, and I found the records for a journal. The article in question is from a previously published book, but was published in the journal article as a section. [This is that article](http://www.lituanus.org/1966/66_2_01Ivinskis.htm).
I just need to know if this is considered a book source or a journal source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a work was published in more than one place, you only have to cite it once.  You can pick which publication to cite.

Edited to add comment from another answer:

Original source vs secondary source applies to works that are quoted or described in another work. In this case, the very same article was published both in a book and in an academic journal. Unless I'm reading the OP wrong... If it really is the same article, and it wasn't edited in a way that is significant to the OP, then it's okay to use either source. Just like if you cite a poem it is okay to find it in Norton's Anthology instead of looking up the original book (so long as it's republished in full).